# QueryInterface fails with E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: c++, com, dcom

The following method is a DCOM server method. The COM client and server is running in different WinXP machines. The COM client calls `RegisterClient` method to register callback interface. The problem is `QueryInterface` method fails with error code `E_ACCESSDENIED`. What could be the reason for the issue?

```
STDMETHODIMP CGEMExtension::RegisterClient(IUnknown** ppGEMExtensionEvents, int* nClientId, int* nResult)
{
    HRESULT  hRes = (*ppGEMExtensionEvents)->QueryInterface(IID_IGEMExtension,(void**)&pUnknown);
    return hRes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an E_ACCESSDENIED, it means you have a permissions problem (don't waist your time on firewalls or registrations - the former will raise errors telling you the service is not available, and the latter will tell you the class is not registered or so). COM relies on Windows permissions, so this is what you should focus on.

In your case, if I understand the case correctly, the server actually calls the client, in order to get the right interface. For that, the user running the server should have the right permissions on the client side. A few suggestions:

1. As daramarak suggests, have the server and the client use the same domain user, or the same local user with the same password.
2. On the client, set [this setting](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/506.mspx?mfr=true) to "classic".
3. Give the server's user, if known to the client, additional permissions using [DCOMCNFG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 Very good answer, I would suggest using alt. 1 while getting everything to work, and configuring with dcomcnfg when everything is up and running, You could also use the security features included in the dcom api to get the permissions correct.

Comment: We have two DCOM servers. The QueryInterface method is working fine with DCOM server A. In that case the client object was created with CoCreateInstance method. In the failure case the object was created with CComObject<CExtensionSink>::CreateInstance(&pExtensionSink). Will that be the reason

Comment: @Maanu I don't know. Is everything else the same? I assume the problem is on the server side, but I might be missing something. I'm not sure if this is appropriate for you case, but try to [set a security blanket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692692.aspx) on ppGEMExtensionEvents before you call QueryInterface. First hard-code some username and password of a local administrator on the client, and if that works, work your way to a real, flexible solution.

Comment: @eran your link to DCOMCNFG is dead

Comment: @daramarak, the link still works for me. Is it still dead for you?

Comment: @eran, no it isn't :D

Answer (score 1):

This might be because the correct permissions is wrong on the other computer. Simplest way to check this is to turn on logging with secpol (Local Policies, Audit policy, turn on logging of logon events and object access) then you can see if you are trying to access the other machine.

If you are just testing then I would suggest to use the setting "run as interactive user" on the com object in component services and make sure that you have the same user with the same password on both machines. Then you must be running as the common user on the client machine. Spesifically setting the user to the common user is also possible.

As a general advice to debugging DCOM connectivity: Turn off all firewalls and such to make sure that the connection is working, then turn on security measures one by one, making sure that you leave the correct ports open and that the correct users have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I give you my experience even if it may not apply directly to your specific case.

On Windows 7 at 64bit I have an exe compiled with x64 and a dll compiled at 32 bit.

A COM object lives inside the dll.

The exe (launched by the "normal" user) creates the COM object (on the same computer) asking for `IUnknown` and the creation is successful. Then the exe asks for a different interface through `QueryInterface` and it fails with `E_ACCESSDENIED`.

If I launch the exe "as administrator" then the `QueryInterface` will return with `S_OK`.

I did not investigate further, I suspect there is some policy about the 32 bit - 64 bit interaction.